# Query to calculate the count of numbers that occur in the previous rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table view like this:

```
Id, Picks
5, 1
5, 5
5, 10
5, 20

4, 8
4, 10
4, 11
4, 22

3, 1
3, 8
3, 10
3, 25

2, 3
2, 5
2, 23
2, 24

1, 14
1, 17
1, 20
1, 24
```

with two columns Id, and Picks. The id is repeated four times for each draw which has 4 numbers between 1-25.

I'd like to display the count of each draw numbers that occur in the previous 3 draws.  So for the numbers of the draw with id=5, if these numbers occur once in the draws with ids 4,3, and 2, then they are counted.

So for the above example the count would be like this:

```
Id, Count
5,  3
4,  2
etc.
```

How could I get this result with a mysql query? the table view doesn't have a unique id.

Comment: I only have these columns, I joined the four columns into one in table view, i thought this would be simpler, in which case i had to sacrifice unique id. so in actual table, i have a unique id, and 4 columns for each number.

Comment: How did you get `3` for ID `5`?

Comment: Join the table with itself, `ON t1.id < t2.id` to get the rows with lower id numbers.

Comment: 5, and 4 are ids. 3 and 2 are counts of the numbers that occur in the previous 3 draws.

Comment: Actually, it should be `ON t1.id BETWEEN t2.id-3 and t2.id-1 AND t1.pick = t2.pick`. Then just count the number of rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need something like:

```
select
  a.id, count(distinct b.picks)
from my_table a
join my_table b on b.picks = a.picks
               and b.id between a.id - 3 and a.id - 1
group by a.id
```

Comment: thanks, can you explain why a.id - 3 and a.id - 1?  why not a.id - 4 and a.id - 1 ?

Comment: I think you need count(distinct b.picks).

Comment: Thanks @forpas, I just noticed what you meant. the answer needs an update.

Comment: @Max Fixed. It's (-3, -1) since you want "previous 3 draws"; that is, -3, -2, and -1.

Answer (score 2):

With EXISTS:

```
select 
  t.id,
  sum(
    case when exists (
        select 1 from tablename 
        where (id between t.id - 3 and t.id - 1) and picks = t.picks
      ) then 1
      else 0
    end
  ) counter
from tablename t 
group by t.id
order by t.id desc
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/prrjgSFUZELaLaJY2xgGNQ/0).
Results:

```
| id  | counter |
| --- | ------- |
| 5   | 3       |
| 4   | 2       |
| 3   | 0       |
| 2   | 1       |
| 1   | 0       |
```